# .split with razor details C# asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Want to take the string NPCSkills and have it split into a list

NPCSkills is a prop that includes a string like `"guns = 4, armor = 2"`
I want it to split into a list so I can display it

item 1

item 2

I am doing the .split but not sure what to do now.

```
 string[] Words = (Model.NPCSkills).Split(',');
 foreach (var item in Words)
 {
     <li>
     @item.Words
     </li>
 }
```

`string` does not contain a definition for 'Words' and no extension method 'Words' accepting a first argument of type `string` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+ @item.Words

Comment: you could for example create two lists.  check the prop, and add it the the appropriate list.  in fact you do not need a loop to so this if you use Linq

Comment: you want to show just guns, armor in list and not numbers?

Comment: `string[] Words = (Model.NPCSkills).Split(',');
 foreach (var item in Words)
 {
     <li>
     @item
     </li>
 }`  just remove the **Words** and it should work

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code to convert the `NPCSkills`(`comma-separated string`) to a strongly-typed `Dictionary`:

```
var Words = (Model.NPCSkills)
    .Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Split("="))
    .ToDictionary(arr => arr[0], arr =>arr[1] );
```

Or if you would like to remove the space around the key/value pair :

```
var Words = (Model.NPCSkills)
    .Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Split("=").Select(e => e.Trim()).ToArray())
    .ToDictionary(arr => arr[0], arr =>arr[1]);
```

Now you could render it in a safer way:

```
@foreach(var item in Words)
{
    <li>
        <span class="badge">@item.Key</span>
        <span class="text">@item.Value</span>
    </li>
}
```